# How to Indicate a Nullable Value's Original Data Type in C#

Tags: c#

Is there anything like bool.null to indicate that this is a Boolean type's null value in C#?

Thanks

Comment: You mean (bool?)true; ?

Comment: The default value of any type is `default(T)` - and `default(bool)` is `false`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Boolean` is a value-type. It cannot be equal to `null` at any case.

However, if it is a `Nullable Boolean`, you can directly compare it to null:

```
bool? b = GetBooleanFromSomeWhere();

if (b == null)
    // It is null
```

P.S. There is no "Boolean type's null value".
Classes do not have their "own null values". There is just `null`.

Answer (score 3):

In C# a `null` value is only relevant to reference types. All uninitialized reference types have a value of `null`. Value types however, can never have a value of `null`. They always have an appropriate 'zero' value as their default, so an uninitialized `bool` variable would have a value of `false`. More info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/edakx9da.aspx).

In C# 2.0 however, the [`Nullable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx) type was introduced to wrap value types with a struct that can represent a `null` or real value. So you could kinda say a `bool?` is the equivalent of your suggested `bool.null`.

So long story short, a variable can have a type, but when assigned a value of `null` the type cannot be inferred from the value.

Answer (score 1):

`System.Boolean` is a `struct` not a `class`, it means that it can't be `null`. However you can declare a `Nullable<Boolean>` or `Boolean?` to simulate a nullable value.

```
bool? myBool = null;
if (myBool.HasValue)
{
 //my bool is not null
 //access its value using myBool.Value
}
else
{
  //my bool is null
}
```

If you want to know more aboun nullable types, take a look at this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx

Answer (score 1):

if you want to crate a null able One on your code simply add `?` to the end of datatype like this

```
int? a = null;
bool? b = null;
```

like this :D